# Transact-SQL: stored procedure receive generic table?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

Is it possible, in any way, for a stored procedure to receive a generic table as parameter? I'm trying to use one stored procedure inside several triggers and I wanted it to receive my 'inserted' and 'deleted' tables. Is it possible?
Thanks.

Comment: You are asking two conflicting things here. The first is can a procedure receive a generic table, no this is not possible. But then you say you want to pass inserted and deleted pseudotables to a procedure, this is a totally different thing as you would know the structure. You could use a table valued parameter here but something seems a bit off here. I have a feeling you have a lot of logic being wrapped up in a trigger which is likely going to cause pain in the long run.

Comment: Look into Table Value Parameters... and if using SQL Server 2016 or above... JSON may work too... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters